# Do i have the latest drivers/software on AMD Graphics

Tags: ati, graphics, updates, catalyst

I need the override section on catalyst control center, but I don't have it. I want to know if i have the latest version of any kind of AMD software. This is what Catalyst control center says in the software information section:

-Catalyst version: 12.4

-Driver packaging version: 8.961-12045a-137531C-ATI

-2D Driver version: 8.96.4

-Catalyst control center version: 2.14

-RandR Version: 1.3

BTW, I have the ATI Radeon HD 4850

Comment: If possible, please consider closing some of your other open questions by [selecting the best answer](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1137/how-do-i-accept-an-answer) (if they have one). Consider which answers have been useful and need an upvote. We need users to maintain their questions so that the site can be an effective tool for the next person with your problems. For more details on best practices consider reading [the FAQ on asking questions](http://askubuntu.com/faq#howtoask).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

actually, every Ubuntu's repositories doesn't always provide new softwares in their server. Because Canonical retests and evaluates all new softwares versions that will enter into repos for ensuring the softwares is 100% compatible with Ubuntu versions.

If you want to get the latest versions, you could download from official website software distributor. but it doens't guarantee compatible completely.